# Printing MVC 3 Web page Using Epson PLQ 20 (Pass book printer)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, printing

I have Created a web page using asp.net mvc and open this page in new window and want to print the same using Epson PLQ 20 Printer. But The printer is unable to print that page. What should I do. I have google for this. But Still I have no found solution. Any type of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the issue? Any error messages?

Comment: No actually page is not printing page come out with blank

Comment: do you have it somewhere public, so i can take a look? It's a weird issue to be honest, i suspect something with stylesheets.

Comment: ok, you really should have a staging copy for such issues, make sure you change the passwords after we're done

Comment: I can confirm that it's printing fine for me on my printer (Canon MX 330 on Mac ) , i don't think it's an issue with the code could be the printer acting up, maybe a driver issue? What's your operating system?

Comment: Ok thanks for quick reply one more question can you please give some suggestion about My Printer. Actually I have no idea about passbook printer.

Comment: @DwarikaNath In your printer settings, what software it is using? mine is IBM PPDS and it prints the page.